# Call a Method On Hot Reload

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am making a game using Visual Studio 2022 and C# and I was wondering if it was possible to trigger some code when you hot reload your app (whilst it's running).

I basically have 2 methods called UnloadLevel and LoadLevel that I would like to execute on Hot Reload.

I am building a game and to make levels I have the LoadLevel method that puts all the elements (the platforms, entities etc) from this LevelData static class into the game scene. The UnloadLevel function does the opposite. In order to build the levels fast without making an entire fledged out LevelEditor which would be long and tidious to make, I thought using the Hot Reload function of visual studio 2022 to change the LevelData, hot reload, and automatically see the changes in my level scene without having to unload and reload manually.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you want to do so?

Comment: Hot reload is actualy there for developing purposes, but u can still execute some actions on dispose for unload then in your constructor or init method for load, levels.

Comment: I am building a game and to make levels I have the LoadLevel method that puts all the elements (the platforms, entities etc) from this LevelData static class into the game scene. The UnloadLevel function does the opposite. In order to build the levels fast without making an entire fledged out LevelEditor which would be long and tidious to make, I thought using the Hot Reload function of visual studio 2022 to change the LevelData, hotreload, and automatically see the changes in my level scene without having to load and reload manually. @viveknuna

Comment: @spzvtbg I don't really understand what you mean

To elaborate, I basically just want that when I hot reload, my level unloads, then reloads, in order to place the entites in their new correct place (their new positions that I would have assigned them in before hot reloading).

Comment: You are hard-coding the levels into methods of your app? Sooner or later you'll find that this is a bad idea. You are binding your code too much to the levels and you'll have bugs because you forget to set variables in one level while you do in other levels. Separating data from code is a good idea and forces you into defensive coding.

Comment: Other than that: implement a button that you can press to unload and load the level. The button should only be visible in the debug mode, so make it `#if debug`.

Comment: As of right now that's what I've done but it would be more convenient if after hot reloading reloaded the levels automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [`MetadataUpdateHandlerAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.metadata.metadataupdatehandlerattribute?view=net-6.0) is what you're looking for (originally found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37100)).

Example:

```
[assembly: System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdateHandler(typeof(HotReloadManager))]

public static class HotReloadManager
{
    public static void ClearCache(Type[]? updatedTypes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HotReloadManager.ClearCache");
    }

    public static void UpdateApplication(Type[]? updatedTypes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HotReloadManager.UpdateApplication");
    }
}
```

The setup is a bit weird, involving magic-name methods instead of eg an interface.
Also, note that the attribute applies to the assembly, not the class.

You might see references to ASP.NET while googling this, but don't worry it works fine in eg a console app (using it for a game engine myself).