# Is it possible to hook the Hot Reload button to execute code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2022, hot-reload

There is one specific action of emptying a cache that I need to do sometimes while running in Visual Studio.

I never need to this on production (clearing a very specific cache).

Is it possible to hook the Hot Reload button as some kind of event that I can wire into my code?

- would feel very natural in this case for the developer experience
- saves me from hiding some dev-only buttons in my interface
- no specific commands that someone has to remember

[image: Hot Reload]

I'm thinking about something in the lines of:

```
#IF DEBUG
VisualStudio.OnHotReload = () => SpecificCache.Refresh();
#ENDIF
```

Comment: "would feel very natural in this case for the developer experience" only for the developer experience using Visual Studio, devs using VS Code, Rider, Notepad++, Word, whatever would need to remove that code before their version could even compile. Keep in mind that hot reload isn't a VS exclusive feature, it's a .NET 6 feature

Comment: Hi @MindSwipe,  this is very large internal project (not an open source project) and everyone will use Visual Studio in the foreseeable future. I agree in other cases this might not be a good option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a Method On Hot Reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70631828/call-a-method-on-hot-reload)

Comment: @marsze, I think it does! I'm not on .NET 6 yet, but definitely a reason to switch and try it out!